# Apache Superset "sasl" Installation Error

Tags: python, apache-superset, sasl

I am trying to install Apache Superset on an AWS linux server. I created a virtual environments (2.7 and 3.6) and used Conda and Pip and all have failed.

**I get the environment up and running and simply pip install superset and get this issue:**

```
Failed building wheel for sasl
Failed to build sasl
Installing collected packages: sasl, thrift-sasl, superset
  Running setup.py install for sasl ... error

In file included from sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:254:0:
    sasl/saslwrapper.h:22:23: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Command "/home/ec2-user/superset/superset_env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-xpnens/sasl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-8n1Q7a/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ec2-user/superset/superset_env/include/site/python2.7/sasl" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-xpnens/sasl/
```

From reading it appears there are some lower level dependencies for the sasl library. We have installed several but none seem to work. Help?

Comment: What dependencies have you tried installing? What distribution are you using?

Comment: No dependencies installed. When we try to "pip install sasl" we get the same issue.

Comment: You need to install the library using your dist tools. i.e. under Debian use apt-get install libsas12-dev. Look at the os dependencies at https://superset.apache.org/installation.html

Comment: I believe this is CentOS (Red Hat) based and we followed all the instructions for the dependencies there. The problem may be with the "libsasl2-dev" dependency because when we tried to yum install there was no matching distribution.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue with Fedora, you are gonna have to find an RPM that contains the sasl development libraries. Take a look here https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libsasl&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=

Comment: @will7200 Thanks for this. How did you know which one to use?

Comment: By distro and arch, you should look for cyrus-sasl-devel in your package repos it might have that one, it has the dependencies you need.

Comment: Just to circle back here. We ended up just going with a different server that had the dependencies. Thanks all!